# Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows 8 causes Realtek audio problem

Tags: windows-8, realtek, audio-jack

For a long time I thought it was Windows which randomly caused the headphone audio jack to not work randomly but finally I found out the source of the problem.

I have a dual boot, windows 8 and ubuntu 13.10 , both 64bit, whenever I boot into ubuntu and then boot back to windows, the audio problem starts ,

it is very strange problem, I wanna fix it or at least undrestand how could it happen ? 
how audio on another operating system on another partition, can affect the audio driver behavior on another operating system?

do you think there is a flag or something on the hardware level that ubuntu changes that affects windows ? any suggestion to fix this ?

(some other person also has exactly this problem on tomshardware forums so it is not just me)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem, and I haven't been able to find an ideal solution. However, there is a workaround. My headphones WILL work correctly in Windows if I shutdown the computer first, then boot into Windows. Using 'Restart' from either Ubuntu or Windows will still result in audio problem on Windows, though.

So it's not ideal, but it works for me (i.e. I only use Windows for playing games, and it's a just a small nuisance to shutdown and power on for Windows only).